# Why i can't to change log level for logging categories by config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

It's my config file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Console": "Critical",
      "Default": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

This code i use to load config file:

```
        hostBuilder.ConfigureLogging ( ( context, builder ) =>
        {
            builder.AddConfiguration ( context.Configuration.GetSection ( "Logging" ) );
            builder.AddConsole ( );
        } );
```

But it set an `Information` log level for categories: `System`, `Microsoft` and a `Debug` for `Default`. Where did i make a mistake?

Comment: Why are you configuring the `IWebHostBuilder` instead of configuring `IServiceCollection` as usual in your `Startup.cs`? See https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/samples/SampleApp/Program.cs for example

Comment: @haim770 It's the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a mistake. There are two config files appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json. And system use it in development mode.

Comment: Note that appsettings.Development.json is "hidden" under appsettings.json, it's really easy to overlook it. If you're not sure, check it in File Explorer